# Reducing the conditioning set in a conditional expectation

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ denote a probability space.
Let $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}^n)$ and $Y:  (\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (\Psi, \mathcal{G})$ denote two random variables, where $\mathcal{B}^n$ denotes the Borel sets over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(\Psi, \mathcal{G})$ is a measurable space. Assume that $\mathbb{E}\left(|X|\right)< \infty$.
 Suppose there exists a measurable function $g:(\Psi, \mathcal{G}) \to (\mathbb{R}^m, \mathcal{B}^m)$ such that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(X|Y\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(X|g(Y)\right)
$$
almost surely.

Show that for any measurable function $h: (\Psi, \mathcal{G}) \to (\mathbb{R}^k, \mathcal{B}^k)$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(X|g(Y)\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(X|g(Y),h(Y)\right) 
$$
almost surely.

$\textbf{My attempt}$:

Using the Tower Property, we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X|g(Y),h(Y)) &= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|g(Y),h(Y),Y)|g(Y),h(Y)) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|g(Y),h(Y)) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|g(Y))|g(Y),h(Y)) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(X|g(Y))
\end{align}

Comment: Hint: Tower property.

Comment: @DavidK Ok I added my solution. It's pretty long, but I think correct. I'll think about how to use the Tower property to get a simpler proof.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).